# Volume of a sphere section. Is there enough data?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, volume

I am thinking about a problem that seems easy but I suspect that is not possible solve it with the available data.

Thanks very much!

Problem is this:

There is a sphere cutted in four equal pieces (see diagram), we know the volume of one and the volume of the half slice a+b (as can see, there are two egual half slice a+b into c). With this data we could know the volume of b?

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding *there are two egual half slice a+b into c* Can you clarify please?

Comment: You are saying you know a and c and want to discover b?

Comment: rschwieb, excuse me, I am trying to say that vertical and horizontal parts (a + b) are equal. I only know, c and (a+b) and want to discover b in the sphere.

Comment: If you're saying merely that those two sections are equal, then no, of course there isn't enough information. Just move the lines slightly and you get a completely different volume. You need to know something more about the shaded part.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helping me to reject that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the volume of the piece c, you can deduce the radius of the sphere. If the volume of that piece is $V_c$, then $V_c=\frac14\frac43 \pi r^3$.

You can relate the thickness of the shaded region to its volume too by using integration to get the volume of the shaded region. The integral $\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^t x^2-r^2 dx$ where t is the thickness will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, knowing $c$ is enough to get you the radius of the sphere.  That gives you the volume of a hemisphere.  If you subtract twice the volume $a+b$ you are left with a [spherical cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) of known volume.  From that you can determine the height of the cap, and then the thickness of the slice $a+b$.  That gets you $b$.